# Deny all gets overridden by another location block

Tags: nginx, deny

```
location /_private {
    deny    all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # Workaround PHP vulnerability:
    # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
    try_files   $uri =404;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    keepalive_timeout 0;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/php.socket;
}
```

I would like to deny access to everything, that's in `_private` directory.
When I try to access `_private/a`, I get 403 error, like supposed to. But when I try to access `_private/b.php`, the `deny all` part is completely ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Make your `/_private` location take precedence over the regex match:

```
location ^~ /_private {
```

That's it.

The [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) has good information on which location block will apply to a given request.  To quote:

> 1. Directives with the "=" prefix that match the query exactly. If found, searching stops.
> 2. All remaining directives with conventional strings. If this match used the "^~" prefix, searching stops.
> 3. Regular expressions, in the order they are defined in the configuration file.
> 4. If #3 yielded a match, that result is used. Otherwise, the match from #2 is used.